# Change submit button text and disable it in iOs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have this piece of js code, it works on pc (change text to 'adding...' and disables a button). But on iOs devices only form is submitted, text is not changing. Any ideas?

```
        $(".moveToBasket").click(function() {
            var form = $(this).closest('form');
            var button = $(this);

            button.attr('value', 'Adding...');

            form.on('submit', function() {
                button.prop("disabled", true);
            });
        });
```

P.S. .moveToBasket class html element is 'input type="submit"'

Comment: Can you emulate and inspect what happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago. It seems there are other people who confirmed the bug in Safari: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/306

I solved it like this:

```
$('body').on('submit', form, function formSubmitHandler(event){
    // Shadow the form to prevent infinite loop
    var form = event.target;

    event.preventDefault();

    // If <input type="submit">
    button.attr('value', 'Adding...');

    // If <button>Add</button>
    button.text('Adding...');

    button.prop('disabled', true);

    // Submit the form in a different tick
    setTimeout(function() {
        form.submit();
    }, 10);
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you send me the HTML so I can see what needs to be done,

If it's a button element, you can do button.text('adding...')

Comment: No, it is input element

Comment: Try $(this).attr('val', 'adding...');

Comment: Sorry, try this actually.

Comment: $(this).val('adding...');

Comment: Nope, in iOs it didn't help